# AngularJS changing property name in model

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, datamodel

The data I am receiving is structured like this. I am taking this data and displaying it on to a graph with radio buttons. Each radio button will show the "category name", but actually I need to show a different label for the category name other than what is coming back in the data. For example if the category name is false, I need the radio button to display: "Other" and if it is true I need to display: "Our Company".

```
0: Object
    categoryName: false
    categories: Array[4]
        0: Object
        1: Object
        2: Object
        3: Object
1: Object
    categoryName: true
    categories: Array[2]
        0: Object
        1: Object

<span ng-repeat="testCat in testCategories">
<input type="radio" name="programSelector2" ng-model="testCategoryId" ng-click="load( testCat.id )" value="{{testCat.id}}" >{{testCat.name}}
</span>
```

Need some help with controller logic I'm assuming to update the model based on what the categoryName is.

Comment: how are you getting the data, is it through an ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow three different roads:

- create a function to resolve the value
- create an array to solve the value
- use a condition in the expression

---

**With resolve function:**

```
$scope.resolve = function(key) {
    if (key == 'firstValue') {
        return 'First description';
    } else if (key == 'secondValue') {
        return 'Second description;
    }
}
```

and in the HTML

```
{{resolve(testCat.categoryName)}}
```

---

**With array**

```
$scope.resolve = [];
$scope.resolve['firstValue'] = 'First description;
$scope.resolve['secondValue'] = 'Second description;
```

and in the HTML

```
{{resolve[testCat.categoryName]}}
```

---

**With conditional expression**

Or in the case that categoryName has only true false values

```
 {{ testCat.categoryName ? 'First description' : 'Second description' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create function in the controller like :

```
scope.getCategoryName=function(categoryName){
   if(categoryName === true)
     return 'Other';
   else 
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

and then call it from your html

```
<input type="radio" name="programSelector2" ng-model="testCategoryId" ng-click="load( testCat.id )" value="{{testCat.id}}" >{{getCategoryName(testCat.name)}}
```